# Difference between preference and shared preference? and what should use with Ringtone settings?

Tags: java, android, preference

what is the difference between shared preference and preference? also i want create a ringtone settings what should i use? preference or shared preference? also if there is tutorial to make the ringtone please provide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preference is the UI part that is used to allow modification of shared preferences. It actually uses SharedPreferences inside.

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html):

> Represents the basic Preference UI building block displayed by a
>   PreferenceActivity in the form of a ListView. This class provides the
>   View to be displayed in the activity and associates with a
>   SharedPreferences to store/retrieve the preference data.

Comment: SharedPreference to store data! and perference just UI to show us the menu, Am I right? so i should use Shared perference to code the Ringtone and perference to show the user the menu?